# Can iOS Apps have Login Screen?

Tags: ios, app-store

I need to add log in screen and registration forum to my application, such that the user register or log in to the application,

is it legal issue or my application will be rejected

Answer (score 2):

You can have a log in screen.  Many apps have them.

But Apple has been rejecting apps with a login registration screen, or even a registration web site URL within the app, depending on the exact conditions for that registration.  You may have to get users to register for your app outside your app and/or before running your app.  Make sure to preregister Apple with a demo account for use during app review.

It also helps greatly if your app has some general usefulness even without registering (e.g. banking apps may have a map to the nearest branch even for users who don't have customer account logins, or some public info about interest rates, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of apps that also live on the web and so require some sort of login, e.g. Foursquare, Facebook

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues at all with creating a login screen for your application. When you submit your app to the App Store, you will be asked to provide login credentials for the testing team to login and test your app. I wouldn't force them to go through the account creation process as it may delay your app getting approved.